# c# selenium tests on azure download and confirm report files

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops

We have a group of tests in Selenium/C# which click on download report buttons and then validate the report has been created in the local file. We now wish to deploy these tests with our main test suite which runs on azure in a release pipeline. At the moment the tests run fine locally but not on azure.
To start we have tried different paths such as

```
protected const string DownloadPathExt = "C:\\TestFolder\\Release\\net6.0\\";
protected const string DownloadPathExt = "D:\\a\\r1\\a\\TestFolder Regression\\";
```

I have noticed these are in use during the buils step. This is initially defined here

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", DownloadPathExt);
```

And also here

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(DownloadPath);
```

As you can see from this output the test is looking in whatever folder I am setting but it is not seeing the report file. So either it is not downloading or it is being created in a different folder.

```
2023-06-05T10:52:01.9695830Z  In procedure ReadXLSFileDownloaded
2023-06-05T10:52:01.9696187Z  Checking file D:\a\r1\a\_Pi Regression\.editorconfig
2023-06-05T10:52:01.9696549Z  Checking file D:\a\r1\a\_Pi Regression\.gitattributes
2023-06-05T10:52:01.9696918Z  Checking file D:\a\r1\a\_Pi Regression\.gitignore
2023-06-05T10:52:01.9697378Z  Checking file D:\a\r1\a\_Pi Regression\azure-pipelines.yml
2023-06-05T10:52:01.9697840Z  Checking file D:\a\r1\a\_Pi Regression\azure-test-pipelines.yml
2023-06-05T10:52:01.9698236Z  Checking file D:\a\r1\a\_Pi Regression\TestApp.sln
2023-06-05T10:52:01.9698608Z  Checking file D:\a\r1\a\_Pi Regression\README.md
2023-06-05T10:52:01.9698967Z  Checking file D:\a\r1\a\_Pi Regression\xml_to_nunit.xslt
```

Locally this is finding the downloaded report, in azure it is not. Has anyone got any ideas on what I am missing please?

Thanks in advance.

Kev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted, should anyone need the answer
Setting the download path to "C:\agent_work\1\s" resolvedv this issue
Tests are now finding and reading the downloaded reports.
Coolio

Answer (score 1):

Following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml I would suggest passing System.DefaultWorkingDirectory system variable as env var to test task, e.g.:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Test
  env:
    DownloadDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: $(TestProject)
```

and use it like that:

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DownloadDirectory");
```

It is true that System.DefaultWorkingDirectory = "c:\agent_work\1\s" but for me usage of System.DefaultWorkingDirectory sounds more solid and future azure changes-proof.